# Java get part of muiltipart form

Tags: java, multipartform-data, forms, http-post

I have a formular in which there are 4 files that I need to upload.
Because I'm using OpenCms which automaticly uploads all files in a Folder i don't need to do that for my own.
The Problem now: I need an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` Formular, so the Software can upload it.

Now I can't read my Parameters with `request.getParameter("")` instead I'm using a List of FileItems and an Iterator.
But the `List<FileItems>` I get returns `[]`.

Maybe you can help me with that Problem. Here's the Part of my Code:

```
private void createNachricht(CmsObject cms, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("execute createNachricht...");
    List<CmsProperty> bildprops = new ArrayList<CmsProperty>();
    List<CmsProperty> props = new ArrayList<CmsProperty>();
    Map<String, String> allRequestData = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    try {
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            System.out.println("isMultipartContent");
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(
                    factory);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FileItem> fileItemsList = servletFileUpload
                    .parseRequest(request); // returns [] so it's empty...
            Iterator<FileItem> it = fileItemsList.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                FileItem fileItemTemp = it.next();
                if (!fileItemTemp.isFormField()) {
                    StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder(
                            sanitizeFilename(fileItemTemp.getName()));
                    System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);
                } else {
                    String name = fileItemTemp.getFieldName();
                    String val = fileItemTemp.getString("utf-8");
                    allRequestData.put(name, val);
                    System.out.println("name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("value: " + val);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // more code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files arrive in request stream that can be read once. I guess your CMS has already read this request stream, so it's now empty and ServletFileUpload can read nothing from it.

Ask your CMS for files. Refer to your CMS docs about how to get multi-part parameters that are parsed alongside uploaded files.

Comment: Thank you!
I've build the Form on my own, so i can stop the uploading process.